# why is my nav menu squished together on a 720p monitor?

Tags: html, css

I have an assignment to make a Website for a "Company" & everything is working except the navigation menu... on my 1080p monitor it looks completely fine but on my 2nd monitor which is a 720p it looks all clustered and weird . I looked around the internet and still cant find a way around unless I'm doing something wrong(high chance)

**1080p:**
[image: 1080p]

**720p:**
[image: 720p]

**Code:**

```css
/* addeded through edit for visual representation to be reproduciable */

body {
  background-color: grey;
}


/* Authors CSS */

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(from top gray 60%, black 30%);
  padding: 1%;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 78px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 500px;
  transition: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

header img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 60%;
  margin-right: 58px;
  position: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Brush Script MT";
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
  font-size: xx-large;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: inherit;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  line-height: 23px;
}


/* Media Query for Tablets, Phones, Small Screen monitors, large monitors*/

@media only screen and (min-width:576px) {
  header {
    display: inline-block
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  header {
    display: inline-block
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  header {
    display: inline-block
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1200px) {
  header {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<hr size="0" width="100%" color="white">
<header>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500.jpg"> <br>
  <h1>Auran Network</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Home</a>
      <a href="Product Page/Product.html">Products</a>
      <a href="Gallary Page/Gallary.html">Gallary</a>
      <a href="Contact Us/Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<hr size="0" width="100%" color="white">
<main>
  <section id="ProductSection">
  </section>
  <div class="vl"></div>

  <section class="aboutus">
    <h1>About us</h1>
    <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
    <p>Hello & Welcome to the Auran Network/Gaming... <br> What are we exactly you may ask? <br> We are a Company that sells gaming pheripherals & makes games! <br> We are still a fairly new Gaming Buisness so we barely sell any products but we sell Keyboards,Mouses,Monitors
      & Games. <br> If you want to Learn More about us press the Learn More button to be redirected to the Full Description of what we are as a Company.
    </p>

  </section>
</main>
<hr size="0" width="100%" color="white">
<footer>
  <h1>&copy; Auran Network</h1>
</footer>
<hr size="0" width="100%" color="white">
```

Comment: Can you please share your Js Code @aura

Comment: also add your HTML structure. Also instead of using float, consider to use flexbox.

Comment: I don't understand one thing, why you have three different media queries for the same thing.

Comment: there multiple issues. `nav ul li a { text-decoration: none; list-style-type: none;` makes no sense. an anchor is not a list. Those properties should belong to list element. `<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Home</a>
      <a href="Product Page/Product.html">Products</a>
      <a href="Gallary Page/Gallary.html">Gallary</a>
      <a href="Contact Us/Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>` why not give each anchor a list item instead of groupin git within a single lsit item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go I think this code modification might help you. I have removed your media queries. Converted your display and float to flex.

If you want a bit more flexibility then you can add `flex-wrap:wrap` inside `.header` style also you can also add the same thing inside `.logo-title` to check that style as well. I hope i helped good luck

[*Code Sandbox Link For Sample Code*](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-wood-hdd5b?file=/index.html:260-1687)

**HTML**

```
  <hr size="0" width="100%" color="white" />
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo-title">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500.jpg" /> <br />
    <h1>Auran Network</h1>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Home</a>
        <a href="Product Page/Product.html">Products</a>
        <a href="Gallary Page/Gallary.html">Gallary</a>
        <a href="Contact Us/Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<hr size="0" width="100%" color="white" />
<main>
  <section id="ProductSection"></section>
  <div class="vl"></div>

  <section class="aboutus">
    <h1>About us</h1>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>
      Hello & Welcome to the Auran Network/Gaming... <br />
      What are we exactly you may ask? <br />
      We are a Company that sells gaming pheripherals & makes games! <br />
      We are still a fairly new Gaming Buisness so we barely sell any
      products but we sell Keyboards,Mouses,Monitors & Games. <br />
      If you want to Learn More about us press the Learn More button to be
      redirected to the Full Description of what we are as a Company.
    </p>
  </section>
</main>
<hr size="0" width="100%" color="white" />
<footer>
  <h1>&copy; Auran Network</h1>
</footer>
<hr size="0" width="100%" color="white" />
```

**CSS**

```
 /* addeded through edit for visual representation to be reproduciable */

  body {
    background-color: grey;
  }

  /* Authors CSS */

  .header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(from top gray 60%, black 30%);
    padding: 1%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .header .logo-title {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .header .logo-title h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }

  .header .logo-title img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;

    border-radius: 60%;
    margin-right: 58px;
    position: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 5s;
  }
  .header .nav-bar ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .header .nav-bar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Brush Script MT";
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
    font-size: xx-large;
    border: 2px solid;
    position: inherit;
    margin: 5px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

  /* Media Query for Tablets, Phones, Small Screen monitors, large monitors*/
```

Comment: why add a class to header and navbar and use classes as selctor? `header` and `nav` are both valid HTML elements and as such can be adressed as a selctor without classes. `widows: 100%;` is an invalid CSS value for this property. Besides of that, no reason to use it here at all.

Comment: You can remove them if you like. its just my preference. Also i was having trouble with header html selector inside codesandbox and adding a class fixed it that's why. ```widows``` was a type fixed that it was supposed to be width.

Answer (score 0):

remove the margin right style of 'a' element and following style to li element

```
nav ul li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
/* addeded through edit for visual representation to be reproduciable */

body {
  background-color: grey;
}


/* Authors CSS */

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(from top gray 60%, black 30%);
  padding: 1%;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 78px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 500px;
  transition: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

header img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 60%;
  margin-right: 58px;
  position: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s;
}
nav ul li {
 display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Brush Script MT";
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
  font-size: xx-large;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: inherit;
  border-radius: 20px;
  line-height: 23px;
}


/* Media Query for Tablets, Phones, Small Screen monitors, large monitors*/

@media only screen and (min-width:576px) {
  header {
    display: inline-block
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  header {
    display: inline-block
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  header {
    display: inline-block
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1200px) {
  header {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<hr size="0" width="100%" color="white">
<header>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500.jpg"> <br>
  <h1>Auran Network</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Home</a>
      <a href="Product Page/Product.html">Products</a>
      <a href="Gallary Page/Gallary.html">Gallary</a>
      <a href="Contact Us/Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<hr size="0" width="100%" color="white">
<main>
  <section id="ProductSection">
  </section>
  <div class="vl"></div>

  <section class="aboutus">
    <h1>About us</h1>
    <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
    <p>Hello & Welcome to the Auran Network/Gaming... <br> What are we exactly you may ask? <br> We are a Company that sells gaming pheripherals & makes games! <br> We are still a fairly new Gaming Buisness so we barely sell any products but we sell Keyboards,Mouses,Monitors
      & Games. <br> If you want to Learn More about us press the Learn More button to be redirected to the Full Description of what we are as a Company.
    </p>

  </section>
</main>
<hr size="0" width="100%" color="white">
<footer>
  <h1>&copy; Auran Network</h1>
</footer>
<hr size="0" width="100%" color="white">
```

Answer (score -1):

This is why the link elements are on top of each other/crashed

```
header h1 {
    margin-right: 500px;
}
```

From a quick look, you want to achieve a responsive navbar component with a view for smaller devices but you are not using the best display property for this kind of work (it is still possible though, with hard work and patience, like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_gray) example).

What you need here is [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) property in order to do better work and simplify your life. There are also tons of example on the internet to "copy" or to be inspired.
If you are willing to invest time in your code I strongly suggest you take this road and refactor your navbar according to flexbox rules to have a nice organized navbar.

Otherwise, if it's only the answer you are looking for at the moment, take down some pixel so the elements are fit without crashing

```
header h1 {
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

and adjust the media query by adding some margin to the h1 on a certain view.

But again, I really recommend refactoring and change to flexbox.

Comment: Down-voted for following reason: technical incorrect. There a re plenty reasons to use a margin right of that value and it is nto causing the issue of colliding. Its frankly unresponsive by default but not the main cause of the issue and you could work with it just fine.